# SQL user relationship

Tags: sql, jdbc, relational-database

I have relationship of User to different type of roles.  Each user can be none to all the roles. At the moment the user can be up to three roles.  My user DTO is using user_name and user_id as the primary keys.  I first tried implementing it the user table with each column being the specific row and having true and false value. I instead elected to use a string that concatenate all three roles of that user. How do you implement to support my model written in java and jdbc?

```
CREATE TABLE USERS 
   (    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "CREATION_DATE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "USER_NAME_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("USER_NAME")
```

Comment: You have a bad data model.  You should have a separate table, `UserRoles` with one row per user and per role the user has.

Comment: How would implement UserRoles?  Using booleans or strings or some kind of octal permission system like linux that can tell you what combination of roles that particular user is?  A user can be none or one or many of the three roles and up to three roles.

Comment: Would you also do another table with call user_attributes because each user only needs user_id, user_name, password and user roles as being mandatory information for that user?

Comment: What 'attributes' are storing relative to each user?

Comment: Each user have all the same attributes, a client might have attribute that is different that is not listed but the behaviour essentially divides the type of user role. I'm running a command pattern and the list of commands differentiate themselves.   Any comments???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use this structure:

Tables/Fields:

```
USERS (USER_NAME, USER_ID, USER_PASSWORD, USER_TYPE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
USER_TYPES (USER_TYPE, DESCR)
ROLEDEFN (ROLENAME, DESCR)
ROLEUSER (USER_NAME, ROLENAME)
```

Foreign keys:

```
USERS.USER_TYPE references USER_TYPES.USER_TYPE
ROLEUSER.ROLENAME references ROLEDEFN.ROLENAME
```

ROLEDEFN will have one row per role, and will store a description of each role so that you can keep track of what's what.

ROLEUSER will have one row for each unique combination of user and role. Ie. if there are 3 users each with 3 roles, then it would have 9 rows.

If new roles ever need to be added, you simply add rows, no need to alter the tables.

Here is some example ddl and dml based on your comment -

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a968d/1/0

```
create table roledefn
(
    rolename varchar2(20),
    descr varchar2(40),
    constraint role_pk primary key (rolename)
);

create table roleuser
(
    user_name varchar2(20),
    rolename varchar2(20),
    constraint role_fk foreign key (rolename)
    references roledefn (rolename)
);

insert into roledefn values ('admin','allows you to do admin stuff');
insert into roledefn values ('client','allows you to do client stuff');
insert into roledefn values ('worker','allows you to do worker stuff');

insert into roleuser values ('A','admin');
insert into roleuser values ('A','client');
insert into roleuser values ('A','worker');
insert into roleuser values ('B','admin');

select user_name, rolename, descr
from roleuser natural join roledefn
```

Comment: How would a query or insert for the particular user roles work?  If a user A has three different types of role, i.e admin, client, worker? When I query it, I should have all three roles returned. In another case user B only has one role so they only return one role, i.e. just admin?